# How to click "NEXT" card in the gmail.com webpage using Selenium webdriver 3.4.3?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I want to navigate through gmail.com and log into my account using Selenium.
I'm new to python programming and selenium and hence I don't know how to do that.
In the gmail.com webpage, I can fill in my email account, but then I need to click next card in the bottom. How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

While working with Selenium 3.4.X and ChromeDriver 2.29 & the latest Google Chrome 58.0 you can use the following code block to open gmail, key in your email-id and click on the `NEXT` button:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:\\your_directory\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://mail.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']").send_keys("alphax")
driver.find_element_by_id("identifierNext").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.